# Changing the css of ionic list item with ion-scroll

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm developing an application with Ionic and Angular, and i'm trying to rewrite the css of the list items to display data the way I want.

Here is what I want it to look like :

[image: SAMPLE]

But I'm having some problem setting the padding between the images, it doesn't work at all.

and also the automatic height, I'm using ng-if for wether display the news or not, when not displaying the news I have this empty div showing

Here is my code :

```
 <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-divider">
          Teams
        </div>
      <div class="item" style="height:150px;"  ng-repeat="team in teams">
      <img ng-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/FC_Barcelona_(crest).svg/1010px-FC_Barcelona_(crest).svg.png" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:25px; height:25px"  > 
   <p style="left:50px; position:absolute; color:black; font-size:16px; top:12px">{{team.name}}</p>          <p style="right:30px; position:absolute; top:12px"> Tout</p>
       <i class="icon ion-chevron-right" style="position:absolute; right:10px; color:grey; top:12px"></i>
      <ion-scroll direction="x" scrollbar-x="false" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:50px" ng-if="team.news=='true'">
      <div style="height:85px; width:500px;  position:relative "  >
        <div style="width:110px; display: inline-block;  position:static; padding-right:5px"  ng-repeat="item in items">
         <img src="http://fr.starafrica.com/football/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2015/07/sporever/272576_PALERME_LAZAAR_220215-615x340.jpg" style="height:65px; width:110px"> 
          <p style="font-size:9px; color:black">News1</p>
          </div>  


          </div>
      </ion-scroll>



  </div>
```

Here is also a [plunker DEMO](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/yNgMJq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give **padding-right** to img.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Now you can used to this css i see your demo and suggest to you used to this css

```
.scroll > div > div + div {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do what others have said or 
Try this.

```
.scroll img {
        padding-left: 2px;
    }
```

Demo here:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVXeRy